# Deal with data from spectrometry

Tags: r, deep-learning

I'm trying to predict type of cells (A or B) using data from a spectrometry, here is the shape of data I have :

[image]

I'm facing the following problems : each value of the spectre is represented by a variables and there is not huge difference between the spectre of cells A and cells B (means, I can't say in first approach just by visualising the whole spectre).

Here is an example of plot for a cell A and a cell B :
[image]

How I could deal with such data ? Which model could be better ? I tried a neural network using keras on R but the best I can do is accuracy of 70% and loss of 55%.

The following code is the neural network I tried using keras on R :

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
  layer_dense(units  = 150, activation = 'tanh', input_shape = ncol(train_x)) %>% 
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.4) %>% 
  layer_dense(units  = 150, activation  = 'tanh') %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.3) %>%
  layer_dense(units  = 2, activation   = 'sigmoid')

model %>% compile(
  loss      = 'binary_crossentropy',
  optimizer = optimizer_adam(),
  metrics   = c('accuracy')
)

history = model %>% fit(
  train_x, train_y, 
  epochs = 500, 
  batch_size = 50, 
  validation_split = 0.2, 
  shuffle = 1
)
```

And the result : 
[image]

Is this a good way to use neural network for such a problem ? Could I use more variables by creating ones using the spectre ? Any idea ? Thanks !

Comment: Can you include a plot of some example spectra in your question? More details are also needed (e.g. how many datapoints do you have? What are the details of the neural net and training procedure you tried? Are the numbers you reported for training or test set?). Keep in mind that the spectra may not contain enough information to identify cell type perfectly. Do you have some particular reason to think that it's possible to do better than 70% accuracy?

Comment: Thank you @user20160. I'm not sure this is possible to do better than 70%, my question was more, "it is a good way to do it using neural network ?". I added some plot and the code I use

Comment: What is apparent from the learning curves is that both curves nicely converge with a small gap, but the validation does not start to increase, so it might be that your neural net could be more complex (have more layers). Did you try first overfitting to your training set and then using dropout to deal with overfitting?

Comment: The only way to know whether a neural network is the best method for a particular dataset is to try it, and compare with different methods. R is great because it's so easy to try out different techniques. Everyone has their own favorites, but my number one "goto" is Bayesian Additive Regression Trees (BART), which is implemented in several R packages. I would suggest trying that as well as other popular methods